# Partial derivatives, simple question about notations

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

let $w=f(x,u,v)$ $u=(x,v,y)$ $v=h(x,y)$

Now textbook suggests that :

$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial w}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

Shouldn't this be equal to $\frac{dw}{dx}$ instead of $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$

Comment: yes. ${ {{{{{   }}}}}      } $

Comment: no.  $y$ is still unaccounted for.

Comment: Horrible notation...! They're using $\partial w/\partial x$ for two different things here.

Comment: @HansLundmark How come $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} + A$ then?

Comment: As I said, it's because the $\partial w/\partial x$ on the left-hand side does not denote the same thing as the $\partial w/\partial x$ on the right-hand side.

Comment: @HansLundmark Textbook should have concluded that then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
It is not $\frac{dw}{dx}$ since $w$ depends on two variables $x$ and $y$.

to obtain $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=w'_x$,

use the following

- $$dw=f'_xdx+f'_udu+f'_vdv$$
- $$du=g'_xdx+g'_vdv+g'_ydy$$
- $$dv=h'_xdx+h'_ydy$$

plug $du$ and $dv$ in $dw$ and

factor to get as you said $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}.$

Answer (score 0):

The book is right, since ultimately $w$ depends on $x$ and $y$, so a partial derivative is needed on the left-hand side.